# Oauth with batch application

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth

We have a use case where we wanted to use our Google auth for our enterprise wide application.

Our application is spring boot enabled Java application. I read alot of articles which says that oauth can easily integrate with spring boot web app having some consent screen upfront where the use can put their Google username and password.

But I have application which do not have any user interface. Currently I am using basic auth to do the few role base authentication for all my different endpoints.

Currently, I am using curl and postman to hit any of those api endpoints with basic auth. How I can integrate the Google oauth so that the user can use their own user password before hit any endpoints.

My sole intention is to get identified each user name who interact with any of the endpoints.

Any help is welcome, bear with me I am new to oauth terminology.

Please help me to redirect to the right place or document.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your apps with no UI a rest api or something that will be hit by some other application or by a person? If your intention is for a person to use it, you should create a UI. If your intention is to have some other application hit it, then I can provide further details. You should not expect a average user to understand rest & oauth.

Comment: @SledgeHammer I did let client understand the oauth but can i able to implement the Google oauth considering client will have access to postman only. Also I do have one another services which interact to my current micro service. Highly appreciated your future feedbacks.

Comment: @SledgeHammer also I do understand that oauth has to have with ui in place but searching for other way which help me to identify the individual users who try to do any operations on the api, please suggestion how I can use oauth in this case without ui.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the user for consent to act on their behalf, it is the authorization code flow. That flow is intended for apps that have a UI.

For apps with no UI, like a rest api or something of that nature, you generally use the client credentials flow. This flow is not intended for people as you have to submit a token request to the oauth server, pass it in to your service in the authorization header and handle token validation, expiration, etc. Even if a user is good with postman, it is still a "pain".

I would recommend you add Swagger to your rest api and use the built in client credentials flow.

Spring Boot supports OAuth2 with JWT out of the box. If you throw Swagger on top of that, you can hook that in to either your own authorization server, or in your case Googles.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you share some go to document which has oauth implementation with jwt and backed with Google authorization server. That would help me a lot.

Comment: @IndrajeetGour This one got me up and running on OAuth+JWT: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt. This one has some info on Google login: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login and this one will get you up on Swagger: https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api